# How to read string information displayed on Octave terminal?

Tags: string, terminal, octave, scanf

A third party socket client (mex binary) is continually writing a string on my octave terminal. I have no idea how this mex binary is working... I would need to read (load) this string/text into an octave variable for parsing.

I tried to use scanf, fgetl(stdin) but without success. Can someone help on this?
Thanks!

Comment: Does your mysterious mex function write on stdout for every call (in this case Ander Biguris answer will work) or asynchronous while waiting on input (for example attached to input event hook)?

Comment: Btw, of course the best would be to get that sourcecode and patch this function to return your needed information as return value

Answer (score 2):

Evaluate the function catching its output

```
text=evalc('out=mexfunction(input)');
```